# Как изменить ширину и высоту фигуры через prompt

Tags: javascript, css, prompt

У меня есть код с помощью которого пользователь может написать какую фигуру он хочет (круг или квадрат) и цвет (красный, синий, зеленый) и фигура по его параметрам появиться. Но теперь нужно добавить что бы пользователь мог задать ширину и высоту этих фигур, так же как до этого вводил нужный ему цвет и фигуру

Нужно что бы вылезало окно prompt и в нем можно было вписать ширину и высоту фигуры и потом появлялась фигура с указанной шириной и высотой

Вот что у меня есть:

HTML

```
     <html>
    <head> 
    <title>5111-61</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Untitled-1.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS

```
div1r{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
div1g{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: green;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
div1b{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
}
div2r{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: red;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
div2g{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: green;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
div2b{
width: 150px ;
height: 150px;
background-color: blue;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
border-radius: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
let figura = prompt('Какую фигуру вам нужно?', '');
if (figura == 'круг') {document.write('<div2></div2>')}
if (figura == 'квадрат') {document.write('<div1></div1>')}


let tsvet = prompt('Какого цвета вам нужно фигура?', '');
if ((figura == 'круг') & (tsvet == 'красный')) {document.write('<div2r></div2r>')}
if ((figura == 'круг') & (tsvet == 'зеленый')) {document.write('<div2g></div2g>')}
if ((figura == 'круг') & (tsvet == 'синий')) {document.write('<div2b></div2b>')}

if ((figura == 'квадрат') & (tsvet == 'красный')) {document.write('<div1r></div1r>')}
if ((figura == 'квадрат') & (tsvet == 'зеленый')) {document.write('<div1g></div1g>')}
if ((figura == 'квадрат') & (tsvet == 'синий')) {document.write('<div1b></div1b>')}

let razmer = prompt('Какого размера будет фигура (в пикселях)?', '');
```

Comment: Так и в чём вопрос-то? Если ты мог до этого всё это добавить, то в чём сложность добавить ещё prompt?

Comment: prompt добавить не проблема. как сделать так что бы значение из prompt было переменено потом к файлу css и что бы фигура меняла свою ширину и высоту

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.write('<div2r style="width:' + razmer + 'px"></div2r>')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!❤

Comment: @DmitryTsvetkov Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.